# Django testing: How to test if an instance is part of the model object set?

Tags: django

The wording to this question is clumsy, sorry about that.

I am trying to test whether an instance has been included in model objects. In short is `instance, _ = AModel.objects.get_or_create(...)` is `instance` is included `AModel.objects`.

I am using:

```
self.assertIn(model_name_instance, model_name.objects)
```

but I get the error:

`TypeError: argument of type 'Manager' is not iterable`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objects` is the manager, not a queryset, that would be `objects.all()` for instance. And `get_or_create` tells you whether it had to create the instance or if existed before in the part that you anonymized:

```
instance, created = AModel.objects.get_or_create(...)
if not created:
    # instance existed before
```

Comment: thank you. So as long as get_or_create returns true or false in created. I can infer that it now exists?